# Session is changed during post request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, token

I created application in Laravel 4. Everything is ok on localhost, but when I upload application to public server I always get `TokenMissMatchException`. After some debugging I noticed on every POST request two tokens are created.
This is filter.php

```
Route::filter('csrf', function() {
    $token = Request::ajax() ? Request::header('x-csrf-token') : Input::get('_token');
    if (Session::token() != $token){
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

When I `var_dump()` `$token` and `Session::token()` I get two different values.
Post requests are not ajax.
Can someone help me with this?

EDIT

When I remove CSRF protection I can log in, but when I refresh the page I get logged out, so it must be something wrong with sessions since it's invalidated so quickly

Comment: _“After some debugging I noticed on every POST request two tokens are created”_ – and where/how does this happen?

Comment: @CBroe When I open some form in Firebug, I can see _token value, then if I submit that form the $token contains that _token value, but Session::token contains different token.

Comment: But the session stays intact (same session id on all requests)? Go check if there are any unexpected extra requests happening after the page with the form on it is loaded, via the net panel in your browser’s developer tools.

Comment: @CBroe No, there is not other requests, I get only 1 POST request

Comment: I meant _before_ the POST request, the (presumably) GET request that loads the HTML page with the form in it. // Since you say you got this problem on a public server, can you tell us the address so we can have a look ourselves?

Comment: @CBroe This is the site: http://www.spottunes.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, there *are* two requests where there should be only one …

On line 285, you have

```
<img src="http://www.spottunes.net/" id="imgWrap" …>
```

– and that makes the browser request the same URL that the document was loaded from again. It of course refuses to display as an image, since it delivers the same HTML document again – but I assume that requesting the HTML document itself is what triggers generation of the form token, and that’s your problem right there: After the original HTML document is requested and a token for your form was generated, the same URL is requested *again*, therefor a *new* form token is generated – and when you submit your form, the tokens don’t match any more.

So remove that `img` element (or give it the URL of an actual image as `src`), and the problem should be solved.

---

Btw. you also have a circular redirect from `http://www.spottunes.net/thumbs` to `http://www.spottunes.net/thumbs/` and from there back to `http://www.spottunes.net/thumbs` again and so forth … not pertaining to the problem, but nevertheless something you should look into and fix.

Comment: Thanks, I actually found that site logo was the problem, it pointed to missing image and it returned 404 error, so after I removed this image, everything is ok. Thanks for your help